# Как написать обработчик аннотации?

Tags: java, аннотации, рефлексия

У меня задача написать аннотацию подобную `@Value` в `SpringBoot`. Тоесть любое поле аннотированое `@Prop("${value}")` должно получить значение из `properties` файла. Вопрос с выгрузкой из properties файла не стоит, но с созданием самой аннотации возникли проблемы.

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Prop {
    String set();
}
```

Использование:

```
MyClass {
    @Prop("${value1}")
    private String val1;

    @Prop("${value2}");
    private Integer val2
}
```

Есть интерфейс который умеет получать проперти из `properties` файла:

```
public interface PropertiesLoader {
    get(String key);
}
```

Как реализовать логику `@interface Prop`?

Я так понимаю что нужно использовать `Reflection API`. Что-то вроде:

```
public class PropHandler {
    public void handle(Object obj) {
        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Prop.class)) {
                try {
                    final String value = field.get(obj).toString();
                    field.set(obj, new PropertiesLoader().get(value));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но тогда придется каждый раз писать `new PropHandler().handle(myClassInstance);` и в чем тогда удобство. Как правильно создать обработчик аннотации? Так что-бы я мог поставить аннотацию `@Prop("${value}")` и по ключу из файла значение подтянется. А то что у меня получилось не удобно, проще использовать `PropertiesLoader` на прямую весь профит от краткости использования аннотаций.

Помогите пожалуйста найти решение. Или понять почему решение через аннотацию здесь не нужно. Хотя Spring не брезгует... Спасибо.

Comment: Что касается конкретно вашего кода, то на вашем месте я бы сделал метод `handle` статическим, а вызов `new PropertiesLoader()` вынес бы из цикла.

Comment: @Shockoway спасибо за замечания. Если я вынесу new PropertiesLoader() из цикла то в случае если аннотировано несколько полей будет срабатывать только первая аннотация.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmBr5diz8WA здесь можно под черпнуть необходимую информацию

Comment: @Иван Гладуш да спасибо, отличный доклад. Но дело в том что у меня к сожалению не используется спринг я хотел эмитировать поводение `@Value` как в спринге. А если бы был спринг то я бы и мучатся не стал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особенность спринга в том, что он сам управляет созданием бинов (не вы вызываете конструктор, а Spring). Поэтому он "знает" о каждом созданном в контексте объекте, может управлять его жизненным циклом, оборачивать как угодно объекты и творить свою магию через пост-процессоры.

Чтобы вам повторить это, потребуется реализовать хотя бы минимальный [IoC-контейнер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), который будет осведомлен о создаваемых экземплярах и имеющий возможность через рефлексию править их поля.